# Paypal payment pro PayPal express order not sending confirmation email in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express, paypal-payments-pro

I have a very long standing issue with PayPal Payments Pro in magento. If a customer places an order using PayPal express they don't receive the order email. If a customer pays with card they get it with no problems.

I have spent a lot of time investigating this with no joy at all. I am wondering if other people have had the same issue and if anyone has managed to solve it. I am running magento community 1.9.2.

The IPN seems to be working properly, and there are no orders in the email que.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Have you stopped auto-invoicing ? As Magento for Paypal orders sends an Order confirmation email once it has created an Invoice I believe

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was caused by magento core bug.

In my exception.log file I had the following error:

```
main.CRITICAL: Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/mywebsite/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/templates/info/default.phtml on line 1
```

If you want to fix it, create your own version of file `vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/templates/info/default.pthml` in your theme and change line:

```
<th scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml($label) ?></th>
```

to:

```
<td>
    <?php 
    $x = $block->getValueAsArray($value, true); 
    if(is_array($x)){
        //print_r($x);
        foreach($x as $y){
            echo $y;
        }
    }else{
        echo $x;
    }
    ?>
</td>
```

It's a very basic fix but it worked on my case.